# how i can find missing value from table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i have a table like 
[image]

in that N num of values is there so how can I find missing `ExciseInvoiceNo` in same format that given

```
DECLARE @temp table
(val int)
insert INTO @temp([val])
SELECT  CONVERT(INT, (case when CHARINDEX('/', EXCISEINVOICENO) > 0 Then 
                 cast(substring(EXCISEINVOICENO,1,len(EXCISEINVOICENO) - 3) as int)
            else Cast(EXCISEINVOICENO as Int) end)  ) as ExciseInvoiceIndex
FROM  tblExciseInvoice
 WHERE      CompYearID=109
   AND (InvoiceDate BETWEEN '10/1/2015 12:00:00 AM' AND '03/30/2016 11:59:59 PM')  
 select (select isnull(max(val)+1,1) from @temp where val < md.val) as [from],
     md.val - 1 as [to]
 from @temp md
  where md.val != 1 and not exists (
        select 1 from @temp md2 where md2.val = md.val - 1)
```

i am trying this but not getting result in proper formate

Comment: Please edit our question and provide sample data and desired results.  As written, your question is too ambiguous/broad.

Comment: I attached sample table  please click on image

Comment: You can use [this tool](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) to create nice tables.

Comment: you could use string functions to split the string into two and then use a window (Lead/Lag) function to ensure the "next" record is 1 greater than the current record and when not, flag it, then return all flagged records

Comment: i have table column like  
1577/15
1578/15
1579/15
1580/15 there is n num of same values is there now i have to find missing values from this.so how i can find

Comment: Define the rule for "missing". As I see it, '0000/15' to '1575/15' are missing from your table. So are '0000/00' to '9999/14' and '1581/15' to '9999/99'.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner this number i give for example its started by 1 only

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by missing you mean from the first occurrence of an invoice until the max occurrence of an invoice.  Missing is anything in between...

Maybe your invoices start at 1/15 or somethign and we would then need to LPAD zeros for 4 positions. or however many it can go up to...

[Working SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/242d5/10/0)

Here's an approach

1. Join the table to itself
2. But use join criteria of +1 on the left part of the invoice number
3. and ensure the right parts match.

The downfall to this approach vs lead/lag window functions is that it can't use the indexes since we're manipulating strings thus it could be slow on large data sets.
.

```
SELECT A.ExciseInvoiceNO, B.ExciseInvoiceNo,
case when B.ExciseInvoiceNo is null then
cast(left(A.ExciseInvoiceNO,4)+1 as varchar(20)) + right(A.ExciseInvoiceNO,3) end
as MissingInvoices
FROM foo A
LEFT JOIN Foo  B
 on Left(A.ExciseInvoiceNO,4)+1 = left(B.ExciseInvoiceNO,4)
 and right(A.ExciseInvoiceNO,3)  = right(B.ExciseInvoiceNO,3)
WHERE case when B.ExciseInvoiceNo is null then
cast(left(A.ExciseInvoiceNO,4)+1 as varchar(20)) + right(A.ExciseInvoiceNO,3) end is not null
```

An approach using window functions

[2nd Working Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/242d5/23)

This window function lets you look at the next record ordered by exciseInvoiceNo and then compare results.  We may have to split the order by the right 3 characters first then the left, but **without understanding the nature of your InvoiceNumber Format I can't be certain**.  I use a CTE (Common table Expression) to store the value of the next records invoice number in one data set which we then use string manipulation on.

```
with cte as (
Select ExciseInvoiceNO Ino, 
Lead(ExciseInvoiceNo,1) over (order by ExciseInvoiceNo) compare
from foo A)

Select case when left(INo,4)+1 = left(compare,4)
            and  right(Ino,3)  = right(compare,3)
       then Null
       else cast(left(INo,4)+1 as varchar(20)) + right(Compare,3)
       end as MissingInvoiceNo
from cte
WHERE case when left(INo,4)+1 = left(compare,4)
            and right(Ino,3)  = right(compare,3)
      then Null
      else cast(left(INo,4)+1 as varchar(20)) + right(Compare,3) end
  is not null
```

Comment: Fiddle works... so how can it not be working?   Are you invoices greater in length than 7? 4+ / + 2?  Simply put I can't improve upon this unless I know specifically what's not working.  Maybe either side of the / can be any size in length.  if so we need to split based on the / into different values and compare...

Comment: Better define the nature of your invoices numbers do they all have /?s what does the 15 mean is an invoice # 1023/15 the same as 1023/14? what determines "Missing"  if I have 1023/14 and 1023/16 is 15 missing?  if I have 1023/14 and 1025/14 is 1024/14 missing?  Based on your example, you're evaluating everything to the LEFT of the / to determine if something is missing...

Comment: that /15,/14.etc,is indicating year in which year invoice is created.my query is working but if suppose i want to print in a single column insted of start stop column.so can u just help me on that.though i get my result